# How to send Three characters at a time using socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I have the following buffers stored in two dimensional character buffers :

```
char buff1[][3]= {{0xff , 0xfd, 0x18},{0xff , 0xfd, 0x1e},{0xff , 0xfd, 0x1d}}; // server side
char buff2[][3] = {{0xff,0xfc,0x1e},{0xff , 0xfc, 0x1d},{0xff , 0xfc, 0x18}}; // client side
```

When each of the three characters are sent from server , I receive the respective sequential response of
client. I would like to know , what changes should be made if the buffers stored are of variable size.
That is if buff1[0][0] was 0xff,0xfd,0x18,0xff,0xfd,0x21 and I still want the messages to be segmented in 3 parts.
Here is the flow I need :

```
Server Sends ---> 0xff 0xfd 0x18
Client Responds ---->0xff 0xfc 0x18

Server sends ---> 0xff 0xfd 0x21
Client Responds ---> 0xff 0xfc 0x21
```

Also I tried sending these buffers using socket programming but I was getting the an empty recbuff after first three buffers were sent. Following is my code :

```
//client
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <arpa/telnet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

char buff2[][3] = {{0xff,0xfc,0x1e},{0xff , 0xfc, 0x1d},{0xff , 0xfc, 0x18}};

void read (int sock)
{
    char buffer[256];

    /* Now read server response */
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    int n = recv( sock, buffer, 255, 0 );
    if (n < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR reading from socket");
         return;
    }
    printf("\n%d bytes received buffer is: %s", n, buffer);

}

void mwrite (int sock, char * buf, int size)
{
    int n = send( sock, buf, size, 0 );
    if (n < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR writing to socket");
         return;
    }
    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", n);
  }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server1;

   char buffer1[256];

   if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    /* Create a socket point */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        return(1);
    }

    server1 = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server1 == NULL)
    {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR no such host \n");
     exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server1->h_addr, (char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server1->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons( portno );


/*Connect to server*/
 if (connect( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) ) < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR connecting");
         return(1);
    }    
   printf("Recieving Buffer 1 from Server side"); 
    bzero(buffer1,256);
int i =0;

while(i <  5)
{
    n= read(sockfd,buffer1,sizeof(buffer1));
    if(n<0)
    printf("ERROR reading in socket %d  len %d", n, sizeof(buffer1));

    n= write(sockfd,buff2,sizeof(buff2));
    if(n<0)
    printf("ERROR writing in socket %d  len %d", n, sizeof(buff2));
        printf("\nSent Buffer2 (WON'T TERMINAL TYPE) from client side");
    i++;
}

return(0);
}
```

Server Side :

```
//a simple echo server

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <arpa/telnet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buff1[][3]= {{0xff , 0xfd, 0x18},{0xff , 0xfd, 0x1e},{0xff , 0xfd, 0x1d}};

char recbuf[1024];

void mwrite (int sock, char * buf, int size)
{
    int n = send( sock, buf, size, 0 );
    if (n < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR writing to socket");
         return;
    }

}


void read (int sock)
{
    char buffer[256];

    /* Now read client response */
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    int n = recv( sock, buffer, 255, 0 );
    if (n < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR reading from socket");
         return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         printf("%2x ", buffer[i]);//printing ascii characters
    printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc , char *argv[] )
{
  int sockfd , newsockfd , portno;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buffer[256];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
  if (sockfd < 0 )
  {
   perror("Error opening socket ");
   exit(1);
  }

  /* Initialize socket structure */
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr));
  portno = atoi(argv[1]);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ; 
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

 /* Now bind the host address using client */
  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr)) <0)

  { 
   perror("Error on binding");
   exit(1);
  } 


    if(listen(sockfd,5)<0)
     {
       perror("Error on listen");
       exit(1);
     }
       int k = 1;
       int count = 1;
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
     perror("ERROR on accept");
     exit(1);
    }

     printf("Server Sending (DO TERMINAL TYPE)\n");
         while(1)
         {int i = 0;
          while ((n = write(newsockfd,buff1,sizeof(buff1)))>0)
           {
           printf("Server Sent query to Client %d:%hhX %hhX %hhX\n", k , buff1[count][0], buff1[count][1], buff1[count][2]);
           n = read(newsockfd, recbuf , sizeof(recbuf));
                   printf("Value of n:%d\n",n);
                   printf("Size of RecBuf:%d\n",sizeof(recbuf));
           printf("Server received response from Client: %hhX %hhX %hhX\n\n", recbuf[i+0], recbuf[i+1], recbuf[i+2]);
                   i = i+3 ;  
           k++;
           count = k % 3;

            }
           if(n < 0)
                {
                    perror("Error writing to socket"); 
                    exit(1);
                   }

         }


      close(sockfd);
      return(0);



}
```

Output :

```
Client Side :
./single_client 127.0.0.1 5000
Recieving Buffer 1 from Server side
Sent Buffer2 (WON'T TERMINAL TYPE) from client side
Sent Buffer2 (WON'T TERMINAL TYPE) from client side
Sent Buffer2 (WON'T TERMINAL TYPE) from client side
Sent Buffer2 (WON'T TERMINAL TYPE) from client side
Sent Buffer2 (WON'T TERMINAL TYPE) from client side

Server Side :
./single_sample 5000
Server Sending (DO TERMINAL TYPE)
Server Sent query to Client 1:FF FD 1E
Value of n:9
Size of RecBuf:1024
Server received response from Client: FF FC 1E

Server Sent query to Client 2:FF FD 1D
Value of n:9
Size of RecBuf:1024
Server received response from Client: FF FC 1D

Server Sent query to Client 3:FF FD 18
Value of n:9
Size of RecBuf:1024
Server received response from Client: FF FC 18

Server Sent query to Client 4:FF FD 1E
Value of n:9
Size of RecBuf:1024
Server received response from Client: 0 0 0 // want FF FC 1E

Server Sent query to Client 5:FF FD 1D
Value of n:9
Size of RecBuf:1024
Server received response from Client: 0 0 0  // should get FF FC 1D

Server Sent query to Client 6:FF FD 18
Value of n:-1
Size of RecBuf:1024
Server received response from Client: 0 0 0  // should get  FF FC 18
```

Basically in the response from client I have 0xff and 0xfc constant for all the replies only difference is the third character which changes as per the request from server.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your programs.

First, in both size, you write using :

```
n = write(newsockfd,buff1,sizeof(buff1))
```

That is at each and every write, you send the **9** characters, when you say you want to send only 3

And in order to make it more hard to understand what happens, you write on the console *not what you sent but what you should have sent*

So first send correctly the 3 characters that you say you want to send (for server) :

```
n = write(newsockfd, buff1[count], 3);
```

and please display what you have done !

Once it will be done, test the parameters for server side as you do client side (not very hard ...), and display what happens on client side.

Finally, you should try to use [graceful shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the end or your program, but I must admit it is a more advanced use of sockets